# Find all sets of N addends equal to a given total W

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

How many distinct combinations of N natural numbers sum to a given natural number W?

For example; for $W=16, N=4$ two of the combinations are $(4,4,4,4)$ and $(5,4,4,3)$

*Note: Combination not permutation. $(5,4,4,3)$ and $(5,4,3,4)$ are equivalent.*
*Note: Excludes $0$*.

I'd like to know;

1. Some way to calculate how many combinations there are.
2. Some process to iterate over each combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) of $W$ into $N$ parts.  They define $p_k(n)$ as the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts and show that it is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part exactly $k$.  This then gives the recurrence $p_k(n)=p_k(n-k)+p_{k-1}(n-1)$  The first term counts the partitions that have two or more occurrences of $k$, so if you remove one the largest is still $k$.  The second term counts the partitions that have a single occurrence of $k$, so if you remove one item from that partition, you are now making a partition of $n-1$ objects with largest part $k-1$

Added in response to comment:  Yes,if $k \gt n$ there are no partitions of $n$ with a part of $k$.  For iterating over them, I would start with the largest possible part and go down.  The largest part can be at most $W-N+1$, in which case all the rest must be $1$'s.    The largest part must be at least $\lceil \frac WN \rceil$.I would write a routine list(W,N) that loops over the largest parts, calling list(W-largest part,N-1) and prefacing each list with the largest part.

Comment: Thank you for putting a name to the problem! :-) I've read that wiki page and the section... took a bit to wrap my head around. It doesn't say, but I think if $k > n$, $p_k(n) = 0? I think an implementation of the function would then be; `function p(k,n) { return (k<1||n<1||k>n)?0:(k==1||k==n)?1:p(k,n-k)+p(k-1,n-1); }`.

Comment: Also, any thoughts on the iteration part of the problem? This question is related to another question I've posted - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590116/find-combinations-of-n-sets-having-no-more-than-one-item-in-common