# An algorithm to generate all unique combinations of addends for a sum, from a range of small addends which are greater than 1?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, integer-partitions

I'm looking for an algorithm to generate all unique combinations of addends for a given sum, within a certain given range of addends. The size of the sum could range from two digits to five digits, while the minimum and maximum of the range of addends will generally be positive single-digit numbers greater than $1$.

I would also be happy to find an algorithm that generates all permutations of such addends within the range because I think I could figure out how to eliminate the duplicates.

The application of this problem is dividing a group of legislators into a number of multi-member districts of limited size. If we have $L = 19$, minimum district size $min = 3$, and maximum district size $max = 6$, the unique combinations I generated by hand are:

- $(4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)$
- $(4, 4, 4, 4, 3)$
- $(5, 5, 5, 4)$
- $(5, 4, 4, 3, 3)$
- $(6, 5, 5, 3)$
- $(6, 4, 3, 3, 3)$
- $(6, 5, 4, 4)$
- $(6, 6, 4, 3)$

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590084/find-all-sets-of-n-addends-equal-to-a-given-total-w) which seems relevant but I have no math background, so I didn't really understand what I read there or when I followed the link to Wikipedia's page on partitions.

Comment: The question you linked asks the number of ways to partition a number with constraints on the number of partitions, which is not directly related to your problem, which is to find an *algorithm* to generate all partitions with size restrictions. Finding an algorithm should be much easier than calculating the number of distinct partitions.

Comment: In the 18th century, Boscovich and Hindenburg developed algorithms for generating integer partitions.  Perhaps their work can be modified to your situation (or might cover it already).